# Automatically launch a program or action when an external drive or disk is connected

Tags: usb, automator, external-disk, filesystem

I have an external drive. Is it possible to launch a program or perform an action when I connect it or plug it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Marco Polo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) can perform actions (you specify) based on attached USB devices.

Edit: MarcoPolo isn't supported anymore, but there is a maintained fork of it: [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/)

Comment: Thank, it works! Steps to configure Marco Polo: (1) Create a context, e.g. `DTVP` (2) Plug the drive, create a *USB* rule for this context and increase its confidence to 100% (3) Setup an *Open* action for `/Volumes/DTVP/Mac/DTVP.app`. Voilà!

Answer (score 2):

The likely most robust solution is to create a `launchd` job with the `StartOnMount` property set to `-boolean YES`:

> `StartOnMount <boolean>`
>   This optional key causes the job to be started every time a filesystem is mounted.

This is how Time Machine does it (see `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-attach.plist`).

You need to check if the desired `/Volume/...` is available, but in my experience, it's faster than using Folder Actions.

Comment: Here's is an interesting link about launchd approach: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=32534

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been posted in the MacRumors forum here:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1029207

The specific suggestion there is to use the application MarcoPolo.