# How to run Applescript on Disk mount

Tags: macos, applescript, external-disk, mount, automount

I want to run an Applescript when I mount a specific disk. It isn't if the script is located on the disk or not, it should just run when OS X mounts the disk.

I tried to accomplish this with folder actions, but it looks like it isn't possible to do it this way.

**Clarification:**

1. I get home with my Macbook
2. I plug my USB Hub into the device
3. External disks are mounted in OS X
4. My Applescript gets run, does some stuff on those disks

I want to automate step 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically launch a program or action when an external drive or disk is connected](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5988/automatically-launch-a-program-or-action-when-an-external-drive-or-disk-is-connec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention under which context you are mounting the disk, but what about going the other way and mounting the disk with the Applescript?

I mention context because when mounting a disk with Applescript is the big caveat that if it is a network volume, and the network is password-protected, then the user name and password would have to be stored as plain text in the script for a seamless execution.

**UPDATE:** [A bit of searching found a similar question elsewhere.](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=154499&postcount=6) Essentially, a script can be made to do this by applying the script as a Folder Action to /Volumes:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    repeat with aItem in these_items
        tell application "Finder"
            if (local volume of aItem) and (name of aItem is "[Name of Hard Drive]") then
                -- do something with the drive
                -- eject aItem
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: I don't want to mount a disk with AS, I want to *run* an AS when a disk gets mounted. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: I understood the question, but I don't think it is possible to do this very easily. I did, however, tooled around a bit and found something that should work with a bit of tweaking to meet your needs.

Comment: I made some small modifications to the script. Works fine :)

Answer (score 12):

The likely most robust solution is to create a `launchd` job with the `StartOnMount` property set to `-boolean YES`:

> `StartOnMount <boolean>`
>   This optional key causes the job to be started every time a filesystem is mounted.

This is how Time Machine does it (see `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-attach.plist`).

Comment: I feel like this is the most robust solution, as it is dependent only on launchd, which is where "this sort of thing" properly resides.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Finder FolderAction that monitors /Volumes. When a new folder appears, that means a new disk has been attached. Now your FolderAction can run an Automator action, AppleScript, or shell script to do your thing.

Answer (score 1):

[MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) can do actions based on disk attachment.

Comment: This app is discounted, for now should use maintained fork: http://www.controlplaneapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create an Automator application chaining the 3 following actions :

- Get Specified Finder Items
- Mount Disk Image
- Run AppleScript

Comment: Again, I don't want to mount an image or a disk with Applescript, I want to run a script when a disk gets mounted. I can't find a way to accomplish that with your steps.

Comment: Yep, i see after clarification that it doesn't work because that's hard drive you're mounting (and not image disk).

Comment: As your answer addresses a different question than what is asked, you should consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, this can be applied to specific folder/mount points and is great to use when mounting a USB flash drive for example...

http://www.jbmurphy.com/2011/07/15/os-x-running-a-script-when-a-usb-drive-is-inserted/