# Automatically move files when inserting SD card?

Tags: automator, sd-card

Is there a way to detect the insertion of an SD card so it would be possible to automatically move specific files (photos in subdirectory) to another location? I do not want a photo application to take control.
Even better, when I put the card in, I get asked whether to move the files.
I would like the files to be moved directly to a shared folder..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically launch a program on a freshly connected USB flash drive](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5988/automatically-launch-a-program-on-a-freshly-connected-usb-flash-drive)

Answer (score 2):

From [**this question**](https://superuser.com/questions/65127/is-it-possible-to-run-an-automator-workflow-when-a-usb-device-is-connected/65136#65136) on SuperUser, try [**MarcoPolo**](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/)

Or, you could use [**folder actions**](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/apps-and-utilities.html#automator).

From [**this tutorial**](http://automatorworld.com/archives/auto-detect-mounted-volumes/):

> - Go to File > Save As Plug-in.
> - Choose Folder Action from the pop-up menu.
> - In the Attach to Folder pop-up, select Other…
> - In the resultant open dialog, hit cmnd-shift-g. This will bring up a small sheet labeled Go to the folder:.
> - In this sheet, type /Volumes/, and hit the Go button, then hit Open.
> - Hit the Save button in the Plug-in sheet.

Comment: "With this trick, any mounted device will trigger the attached workflow." I only want my SD card to trigger the workflow, or the presence of its directory structure.. can that be done?